# default case in a PHP switch-case statement doesn't really work as the default?

Tags: php, switch-statement, http-post

I'm using the following PHP code, on a page that a user reach on after submitting a form with a certain `foo` input name in it, which this PHP code processes, and decides to which URL that user be forwarded accordingly.

I've just noticed that If a user does not enter that page with an `foo` input name (for example, let's say the form on the previous page had a `vvv' as the input name instead, due to some error),
then this PHP code would not send the user to the default URL. instead, it would refresh itself every 3 seconds in a loop.

Why? shouldn't the default value be obtained in case of any error, including the above scenario?

CODE:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['foo'])){

    switch ($_POST['foo']) {

    case "aaa":
        $url = "http://www.aaa.com/";
        break;

    default:
        $url = "http://www.bbb.com/";
    }
}

header( "refresh:3;url=$url" );


?>  
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.test {display: block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
test
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding break; to the default case

Comment: @DamienPirsy @User8889 `break` will skip `switch` and anyway will continue to `header` part

Comment: @User8889 doesn't help..

Comment: When this problem happens, what does `var_dump($_POST['foo'])` show?

Comment: When I add `<?php var_dump($_POST['foo'])?>` to the body, nothing new is showing.

Comment: Can you show us the form?

Answer (score 0):

1) I think you are messing with `$_POST` and `$_GET`. `Get` params are visible in URL, `POST` is not shown in url.

2) If there is no `$_POST['foo']`, than it will throw error, because there is no set `$url` variable. Better change to this code:

```
if(isset($_GET['foo'])){

    switch ($_GET['foo']) {
        case "aaa":
            $url = "http://www.aaa.com/?foo=bbb";
            header( "refresh:3;url={$url}" );
            break;
        default:
            $url = "http://www.bbb.com/?foo=aaa";
            header( "refresh:3;url={$url}" );
    }
    die(); // Optionally, if you wish not to continue any script
} else {
    /* Show default code */
}
```

Comment: this is not an option, as the page must process a form that is being submitted with a POST method.

Comment: @Bucky Than just change `$_GET` to `$_POST`, but you can't send params with `header`, you must use `cUrl`

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that the `switch` snipet is reached when this page is navigated to without `foo` parameters.

In your case, the `$url` has not been initiated yet (may be the `if` condition was failed). So that the `header` function will actually send the browser this header: `refresh:3;url=` (empty string after `url=`), which cause the browser refresh with **current** url every 3 seconds.

Comment: What do you mean by verify it? what your'e saying is basically the cause of the problem (as it would work fine if a `foo` parameter was submitted at the form), but I would expect that the `default` would work at any case, isn't that the purpose of the default, to handle such cases so that there won't be empty strings?

Comment: The default doesn't help if you never get to the `switch` statement in the first place. You skip over that whole block when `isset($_POST['foo'])` is false.

Comment: You can `die` right after the `switch` function or right before `header` function and `var_dump` the value of `$url`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.bbb.com/"; 
if(isset($_POST['foo'])){

    switch ($_POST['foo']) {

    case "aaa":
        $url = "http://www.aaa.com/";
        break;

    }
}

header( "refresh:3;url=$url" );


?>  
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.test {display: block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
test
</body>
</html>
```

It would be better if you set the default url at the top. So even if none of the case get match. Default value will always be there. If the value in case gets matched, then it will be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Does `$_POST['foo']` has any value at all?
Try dump the value to check if there is anything in it:

```
var_dump($_POST['foo'])
```

If the result of this is null then there is an error in your form.

Something like this should work:

```
<form method='post' action = $this->url()>
  <div>
    <input type='text' name='foo' value='foo'>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'>
  </div>
</form>
```

And the action:

```
if(isset($_POST['foo']) && !empty($_POST['foo'])){

    switch ($_POST['foo']) {

    case "aaa":
        $url = "http://www.aaa.com/";
        break;

    default:
        $url = "http://www.bbb.com/";
    }
}
```