# creating a <a href> element once an unexpected delay in PHP header redirection occurs?

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers, server-side

I have a page with a form in the POST method, in which the user posts a `z` value,
to the following PHP page that process it, and redirect the user accordingly:

```
<?php
{

if(isset($_POST['z'])){

    switch ($_POST['z']) {

    case "a":
        $url = "http://www.a.com";
        break;

    case "b":
        $url = "http://www.b.com";
        break;

    default:
        $url = "http://www.default.com/";
    }
}

header( "refresh:0;url=$url" );

}
?> 
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.wrap{
    margin-top: 25%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
You are now being redirected.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Usually this seems to work ok, but today I have received a complaint from a certain visitor that said that the message "You are now being redirected." kept showing and he was never redirected.

I Saw on the server logs that he tried several times to do this (say him posting the form at least 3 times).

1. What could have caused this issue? (the code in the form haven't change).
2. To try to handle such cases, **I thought about giving the user the option to click on a `a href` link to `$url`, but I want this link to show up only after 5 seconds** (meaning in general, most users would never see the link, as the header refresh should occur in 0 seconds). yet I want ALL users to see the message "you are being redirected".

a. I am not sure this would necessarily solve the problem, since if the problem origin was that the `$url` value was empty, such a link would not help.

b. I don't want the user to be able to see the link destination by viewing the page source, unless he fits the 5-seconds delay category. therefore I don't think using Javascript suits here, because it's client side, right? **So I'm looking for a PHP server side solution - that would load the page with everything as it is now, but would also add a `a href` element after 5 seconds. Is there anyway to do this?**

EDIT:
here's the form:

```
  <form action="redirect.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
  <input name="z" type="hidden" value="a"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Go"></form>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as javascript?

Comment: @richieahb He'll need to use JS if he wants to change the DOM dynamically after a timeout.

Comment: Since the redirect occurs on the server-side the user should never see the message in the first place.

Comment: @JayBlanchard with the current code posted, users do see the message.

Comment: @richieahb maybe there's a JS solution for this as well, I'm not sure

Comment: Are you working with http://stackoverflow.com/users/3406294/bucky? This code looks very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25993197/default-case-in-a-php-switch-case-statement-doesnt-really-work-as-the-default/25993356#comment40705417_25993356

Comment: @Barmar yes, let's stay on the subject though :)

Comment: If they are seeing the message then there is something else wrong here. Why do you have additional curly braces in your code? The ones that wrap all of the PHP? It is obvious that `z` is never set. How are you posting to this code?

Comment: The redirection only occurs if `$_POST['z']` is set. Could your user be getting to this page without having submitted a form? That would leave them stranded on a page with a notice about redirection but no actual redirect occurring.

Comment: @JayBlanchard why is it wrong? that's exactly how I want the page to work, make a PHP redirection while showing them a transitional message. the curly braces were part of an IF/ELSE statement I took off as it's unrelated to the question. I guess you can ignore them

Comment: @ialarmedalien I thought about it as a possible reason, but it wouldn't make sense in my case, as the same form is handled for all users, and always contains a `z` value.

Comment: It's wrong because the redirect should occur unless `$url` is empty. If `z` is never set then `$url` *is* empty and no redirect will ever occur. Show us the form.

Comment: @rockyraw That is on subject, because both questions seem to be about why `$url` is not getting set properly, so the redirect is failing.

Comment: @JayBlanchard not sure I understand you. are you suggesting the code is wrong? you can test it and see that it's working just fine.

Comment: There should ALWAYS be a fallback - users manage to do crazy things that devs can't anticipate or predict.

Comment: No, I can test and see that it is not working. If `z` is not set the switch statement never runs. If the switch never runs `$url` never gets set to anything, including the default. It is only if `z` is not set that the user will see the message, otherwise the redirect occurs before the message is ever shown.

Comment: @ialarmedalien I guess that's true, but a fallback wouldn't help me to discover the cause of such problem; I can however define a default `$url` already in the beginning of the code. but I'm not sure the problem that the said user experienced occured due to a `$url` value

Comment: @JayBlanchard that's true, but I want everyone to assume `z` is always set. unless someone can provide a scenario in which it wouldn't be set, provided that the page with the form always contains a `z` value.

Comment: I suggest you put the fallback in place and then see if you get problems. As it is, someone who navigates directly to this page will get stuck there without the page redirecting.

Comment: Without seeing your form you cannot always assume that `z` is set unless you set it as @Barmar suggest in his answer.

Comment: `z` is not a dynamically generated value on that form, so it's a pretty safe assumption. anyway I'm also mainly looking for a `a href` delayed creation method

Comment: To answer this - "So I'm looking for a PHP server side solution - that would load the page with everything as it is now, but would also add a a href element after 5 seconds. Is there anyway to do this?" the answer is no, it cannot be done with PHP.

Comment: at first I thought maybe the `delay` command could help, but it simply delayed the whole code, I thought maybe there's a similar command which doesn't effect the rest of the code

Comment: There is one thing that you could do if you do not want to use Javascript, a meta-refresh with a redirect. This redirect could occur after 5 seconds and can be to another page that has the link in it. http://webmaster.iu.edu/tools-and-guides/maintenance/redirect-meta-refresh.phtml

Comment: do you mean using a META refresh as a fallback, altogether with the current php refresh?  that's an interesting suggestion... though is there a way to hide the link? a user can view the source of the PHP page, see the location of the fallback redirect, go there, and inside see the link

Comment: @JayBlanchard also, what if the page keeps looping within the shorter PHP refresh period? it would never get to the META refresh, no?

Comment: You would have to refresh to another page after five seconds. That page could contain the link - meeting your requirement for showing a link or it could refresh to where you desired the user end up in the first place. Looping? There wouldn't be any looping? Did you win your contest with Bucky? Why are you worried about a user viewing the source. Do *your* users do that often? The cannot see the source of the PHP, just the source of the meta-refresh so I am not sure what you're concerned about @rockyraw

Comment: @JayBlanchard Do you suggest META refresh as a fallback? If so, I don't understand how it is supposed to work, since the PHP refresh would always take place: if it is successful, visitor would get redirected. if unsuccesful, visitor would be looping inside the same page, since the time for the PHP refresh is always lower than the time for the PHP refresh.

Comment: I am suggesting meta-refresh as your only alternative, sans JavaScript, to do what you want to do.

Comment: @JayBlanchard but the redirect needs to be dynamically generated, thus it should be `<META http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=<?php echo $url ?>">`. now, if that's working, there's no reason that a PHP refresh wouldn't work, as both are using the `$url` value.. unless I'm missing something here

Comment: You're missing a lot based on your questions and responses to the answers. The meta-refresh would lead to a page that has the link your need your users to click. You can delay a meta-refresh for 5 seconds, after which you can redirect to another page. Is the link that you have discussed also supposed to be dynamically generated? Since `$url` is *never* set in your example I would expect that you would redirect to the default.

Comment: url is set indeed. see the form: `<input name="z" type="hidden" value="a"/>` , the PHP file would process this to `$url = "http://www.a.com";` all links are supposed to be dynamic whether a PHP referesh or a META refresh lead to them. only static link would be a default error page, that would serve for my error monitoring purposes. hope now it's clear.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the default value before the `if` instead of in the `default:` case:

```
$url = "http://www.default.com/";
if(isset($_POST['z'])){

    switch ($_POST['z']) {

    case "a":
        $url = "http://www.a.com";
        break;

    case "b":
        $url = "http://www.b.com";
        break;
    }
}
```

This way, if `$_POST['z']` isn't set for some reason, they'll still get the default redirection.

Comment: I will, though I would take this answer as a helpful comment, it doesn't really address my main 1+2 questions. thanks.

Comment: None of us can figure out why #1 is happening. And #2 won't work for the reason you gave in `a`, unless you want the fallback to use a hard-coded default URL.

Comment: And the problem in `b` will also exist. There's no way to put the delay on the server, it has to be on the client.

Comment: If you want a delay to show a link you will have to write some JavaScript @rockyraw If you coded this as Barmar has done you would never need the JavaScript *and* the user would never see the message unless they navigated to this page without using the form to get there.

Comment: @JayBlanchard my main concern is to make the visitors get redirected to either `a.com` or `b.com`, so if there's any problem that is not related to the way `$url` is being defined in the first place, I would need such a link, as sending visitors over by default to `default.com` is not something I would like to do at all, besides for error-monitoring purposes.

Comment: Then you have to make sure that `z` is a posted. But, despite numerous requests, you will not show us the form so we cannot tell if there is a problem there or not that would hamper `z` being set.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I've edited my post to show the form.
the question is whether any of you can think about a reason for `#1`, could this be a problem with the server, or the browser (maybe it doesn't want to perform the header refresh) And then, maybe adding a `a href` fallback link would help, or does it necessarily rely in the code, assuming `z` is always posted.

Comment: All I can think of is that the user is linking to your page without going through that form. Does your web log say that the form is the referer?

Comment: @barmar that's impossible as I've created a method not allowed error (not shown in the code) for any user trying to access this page without a POST method. yes form is the ref.

Comment: Is this user the only one having the problem? Maybe there's something weird about his browser.

Comment: it's hard to tell as I can't really get in touch with users. that one has emailed me. what I fear is that this can happen with other users and I wouldn't be able to tell, so I'm trying to both find possible causes and possible remedies.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is that you put an `else` clause that sends you email or logs something containing all of `$_SERVER` and `$_POST` whenever `$_POST['z']` is not set, so you can gather data that might help diagnose it.